# How to find words contained and not contained in a list in R

Tags: r, list, text

I have lists of bigrams

```
list<-c('Financial loss','Day Trading','Trading loss','Trading criteria')
```

i Need to create a vector which can extract bigrams based on contained word and does not contain words.

For eg: I need to extract only Trading loss from the list so if i pass

`extracted bigram<-select(list,'Trading',-matches('Day|criteria')` but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `grep('Trading loss', list, value = TRUE)`??

Comment: That will work , but I need to remove Bigrams which contain similar word as shown the example above.

Comment: there are no bigrams that contain Trading and loss apart from Trading loss. So this will give you the expected result

Comment: I think he gave a simple example, but if in his real life application is more complicated, your answer will not work.

Comment: The point here is to come up with simple representatios of the problem

Comment: then he could do: `grep('Trading', grep('Day|criteria', list, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE), value = TRUE)`

Comment: `select` is used to keep/remove columns in a dataframe with certain column names. You are putting a vector into select. Vectors don't have column names, so it doesn't make sense to remove column names that match 'Day|criteria'.

Comment: Thanks Onyambu,it worke, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that I would create a two step operation, first to filter bigrams without a set of words and the those with the words your are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
librar(stringr)

list <- c('Financial loss','Day Trading','Trading loss','Trading criteria')

bigram <- stringr::str_subset(list, pattern = "Day|criteria", negate = TRUE) %>% 
  stringr::str_subset(pattern = "Trading")
```

If your have a vector with the list of words you can create a patter using the paste function.

```
pattern <- paste(c("Day", "criteria"), collapse = "|"))
```